# Converting decimals into a comma place in excel for a percentage

Tags: excel, vba

I'm try to convert a cell from 19.53% to 19,53% without changing system settings in excel.

The farthest i've gotten to doing this is to use the substitute function to manually change out the decimal place, but it doesn't retain the percentage formatting. Is there a way to change this that would also account for larger numbers such as 223,55%?

Thank you.

Comment: so you tried: `=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"0.00%"),".",",")`? It will need to be stored as text unless the local settings are changed.

Comment: Unless the conversion is for *display only* then I'd caution against doing this

Comment: You can give regex a go. If you are using google sheets, they already have support for regex else you can give this a go. I found the answers cool so I am sharing this.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)